# How to get the current id from an outer query in a nested select

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to fetch the most common value from a column when I group entries.
I figured I have to use a `GROUP BY` in order to get that working. I have the following query:

```
SELECT post_id, (SELECT browser from visits WHERE
id = ? GROUP BY browser ORDER BY count(browser)
DESC limit 1) as common_browser, count(id) as visits FROM `visits` group by post_id
```

On the "?" I want to pass the ID of the group, it does what I'm trying to do if I pass a parameter to it, i.e: `id = 1`.
If there's any other way to accomplish this, please let me know!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Querying with " SELECT post_id,browser, count(post_id) as visits FROM `visits` group by post_id "  returns the following
https://imgur.com/a/XeADnBt

But the browsers that are being print aren't the most used ones, but rather, the last one that visited the post, the desired result would be using the query I submitted in my question. I want to retrieve the MOST COMMON VALUE in the "browsers" column, instead of the last one comitted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT post_id, (
    SELECT browser
    FROM visits AS v1
    WHERE v1.post_id = v.post_id
    GROUP by browser
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1) AS common_browser, COUNT(*) AS visits,
FROM visits AS v
GROUP BY post_id
```

Comment: You rock, dude, too bad I can't vote you just yet, kudos to you for saving my bacon!